# How to inherit a view created with Odoo Studio?

Tags: odoo

I tried this and worked for a while and now it's starting to throw errors. I guess it can't be done this way. Is it possible to achieve it in another way?

Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<odoo>
    <record id="view_res_partner_finan" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res_partner_finan</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="studio_customization.odoo_studio_res_part_96c3b415-a333-436c-9b90-db13f23de750"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='studio_page_6zNV9']" position="replace">
                <page name="financ" string="Inf. Financiera ">
                    <group>
                          ...                      
                    </group>                    
                  </page>               
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: you d rather not mix odoo-studio Views with your own custom module.  Just inherit in Back-Office Views (located in Configuration > Technical > Views)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to change in view created by studio, you can change it from studio itself.

Enable developer mode and then open the view in studio, then in the left side of studio select `View` tab and then click on `</>XML` button, You will see a dropdown list above the XML code select the Odoo studio view and change it as per your need and then click save button.